# How do you call an instance with one parameter?

Tags: java

```
public void remove(String name, int population, double area, String continent) {
    /* Make a new country object for removing */
    Country removeCountry = new Country(name, population, area, continent);

    /* Linear Search for the instance we want to remove */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (removeCountry.equals(catalogue[i])) {
            catalogue[i] = catalogue[size - 1];
            catalogue[size - 1] = null;
            size--;
        }
    }
}
```

Okay so this is in a different class and I want to replace line 1 with,

```
public void remove(String name)
```

but I can't because on the third line, I have to replace population and area with a value, for the continent, I could just replace it with "" and it would work.

```
Country removeCountry = new Country(name, [value], [value], "");
```

In the main class, I want to be able to input this code,

```
myCountry.remove("Canada");
```

So basically, I want to somehow override my primitive type parameters by I don't know how.

Comment: So if you just want to remove the country with that name, why do you need the other three parameters in the first place? Why not just remove those three parameters entirely?

Comment: Do you need to remove the country with specific name or you just want to remove the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking it.

This part:

```java
if (removeCountry.equals(catalogue[i])) {
```

checks if the country you want to remove equals the country at index `i` in your catalogue, and **you already lost** because of this. Because that isn't what you want to do: You want to remove whatever country in the catalogue happens to have a certain name. **Not** the entry in the catalogue that exactly matches the entire record.

Just.. do what you want. You want to remove the item if its country name matches. So, write that:

```
if (catalogue[i].getName().equals(name)) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `Country.equals()` method does not perform the comparison over the `_population`, `_area` or `_continent` data members (fields), any value can be given to the mentioned fields when creating an object instance.

```java
public void remove(String name)
{
    /* Creating new object instance. */
    Country removeCountry = new Country(name, 0, 0.0, "");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        /* Country.equals() method must be independent of _population, _area and _continent */
        if (removeCountry.equals(catalogue[i]))
        {
            catalogue[i] = catalogue[size - 1];
            catalogue[size - 1] = null;
            size--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a simplified answer, you can just use `public void remove(String name) {remove(name, 0, 0.0, "");}`

Answer (score 0):

Java allows for method overloading, unlike some other programming languages. This essentially means you can write this into your code:

```java
public void remove(String name, int population, 
            double area, String continent) {
    
    // your code goes here
    
}

// This will have a different method signature 
// and will allow you to use remove("Canada") 
// on its own.
public void remove(String name) {
    
    remove(name, 0, 0.0, "");
    
}
```

Note that for this to work properly, we would have to assume that `.equals()` ignores the `population`, `area`, and `continent` fields. If it does use these fields, you would need a way to determine the fields programmatically, perhaps by using a country dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In case you **really** want to be able to create an instance of `Country` using only one parameter, you could overload its constructor:

```
public class Country
...
    public Country(String name) {
        this(name, -1, -1, null);
    }
...
```

And then in your `remove()` method you could just do:

```
public void remove(String name) {
    /* Make a new country object for removing */    
    Country removeCountry = new Country(name);
    ...
```

This is assuming that the `equals()` method of the `Country` class compares only its `name` field.

**Explanation**

In java, the same class can have multiple constructors with different parameters. This is called "[constructor overloading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructor-overloading-java/)".

What `this(name, -1, -1, null)` does is that when you instantiate using this single-parameter constructor, it will in turn call the existing four-parameter constructor during instantiation, passing on its `name` argument.